# sed regex pattern for some tricky line (ini section)

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching, sh

I want parse something like a section entry in an *.ini file:

```
line='      [          fdfd fdf         f   ]  '
```

What could be the sed pattern (???) for this line to split the

```
'fdfd fdf         f'
```

out?

So:

```
echo "${line}" | sed -E 's/???/\1/g'
```

How can I describe all chars except `[[:space:]]`, `[` and `]` ? This doesn't work for me: `[^[[:space:]]\[]*` .

Comment: try:       echo "${line}" | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*\\[[[:space:]]*(.*)[[:space:]]*\\][[:space:]]*$/\1/'

Comment: ..Or did you want to match everything except the middle part?  echo "${line}" | sed -E 's/^([[:space:]]*\\[[[:space:]]*).*([[:space:]]*\][[:space:]]*)$/\1\2/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo "$line" | sed "s/^.*\[[[:space:]]*\([^]]*[^][:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*\].*$/'\1'/"
```

You can split the pattern into two:

```
$ echo "$line" | sed "s/^.*\[[[:space:]]*/'/; s/[[:space:]]*\].*$/'/"
```

`awk` works too:

```
$ echo "$line" | awk -F' *[[\]] *' -vQ="'" '{print Q$2Q}'
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention: "Hi, I'm a Mac"... the BSD sed has no -r flag.   BUT: echo "${line}" | sed -e 's/^.*\[[[:space:]]*\([^]]*[^][:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*\].*$/\1/' does work for me! Or with -E option echo "${line}" | sed -E 's/^.*\[[[:space:]]*([^]]*[^][:space:]])[[:space:]]*\].*$/[\1]/'.

Comment: The 2nd solution is easy to understand.

Comment: I forgot to escape '(', ')' if an -e option (not -E) so: echo "${line}" | sed -e 's/^.*[[[:space:]]*\([^]]*[^][:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*].*$/\1/'. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `[[:space:]]` syntax, the outer brackets are normal "match one character from this list" brackets, the same as in `[aeiou]` but the inner brackets are part of `[:space:]` which is an indivisible unit.

So if you wanted to match a single character which either belongs to the `space` class or is an `x` you'd use `[[:space:]x]` or `[x[:space:]]`

When one of the characters you want to match is a `]`, it will terminate the bracketed character list unless you give it some special treatment. You've guessed that you need a backslash somewhere; a good guess but wrong. The way you include a `]` in the list is to put it first. `[ab]c]` is a bracketed list containing the 2 characters `ab`, followed by 2 literal-match characters `c]`, so it matches `"ac]"` or `"bc]"` but `[]abc]` is a bracketed list of the 4 characters `]abc` so it matches `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, or `"]"`.

In a negated list the `]` comes immediately after the `^`.

So putting that all together, the way to match a single char from the set of all chars except the `[:space:]` class and the brackets is:

```
[^][:space:][]
```

The first bracket and the last bracket are a matching pair, even if you think it doesn't look like they should be.

Answer (score 0):

When you say split, do you mean *split into an array*, or do you mean *filter* out all spaces and brackets?

Assuming the value of line number 1 in file.ini is:

```
  [          fdfd fdf         f   ]
```

If you mean array,

```
$linenumber=1;
array=($(sed -n ${linenumber}p file.ini | sed 's/[][]*//g'));
```

will split line number 1 of file.ini into an array and return the values:

```
${array[0]} = fdfd
${array[1]} = fdf
${array[2]} = f
```

If you mean filter spaces and brackets,

```
$linenumber=1;
sed -n ${linenumber}p file.ini | sed 's/[ []]*//g';
```

will return:

```
fdfdfdff
```

and if *neither of those* is what you meant, **please specify the exact output** you are looking to extract from the initial value so that we can address it correctly.

Comment: I meant to get: 'fdfd fdf         f' (whithout quotes, preserve all spaces withing the string: here are trimmed - I don't know stackoverflow grammar for preserving spaces in comments, trim all outer spaces). But anyway, thank you, for your answer.